# Standard SQL Date vs Legacy SQL Date

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed that there is an inconsistent result from Date Function in Standard SQL and Legacy SQL,

In standard SQL, `current_date()` returns a DATE data type, however, in Legacy SQL, `current_date()` returns a String data type.

Then, If I create a table which has 'Date' column by using Standard SQL, later on, when I querying the table using Legacy SQL, I have to format 'Date' from Date Data Type To String Data Type, or the other way around.

Unlike Timestamp Data Type, I can query the same table across different SQL Language. Is there an easy way to query in Standard SQL and legacy SQL without converting between Data type and String type?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy SQL has [very limited support for the civil time types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types#civil-time), so you're better off sticking with standard SQL if possible.

Comment: Make sense to me. Thank you. So it is better to switch from Legacy Sql to Standard Sql?

Comment: That's right. You may also be interested in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql), which talks about some of the differences.